# I am supposed to find the error in the following code but can't find it

Tags: c

I am supposed to find the error in the following code but can't find it.
Shouldn't mf(6) give the same result as mf(i)?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define mf(x) f(&x)

void f(int*);

int main()
{
     int i = 6;

     mf(i);
     mf(6);

 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void f(int* ptr)
{
    printf("%d\n",*ptr);
}
```

Comment: Hint: What is `&6`? What would that mean?

Comment: Did you try compiling it?

Comment: if you compile it you would see exactly what the error is. So why not compile it?

Comment: Don't you just love how some teachers try to get people to understand code that nobody would ever write?

Answer (score 0):

if you compile that code you should have got an error:

> error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand

The unary & (address-of) operator requires an lvalue as its operand.

refer [lvalues and rvalues](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lvalue-and-rvalue-in-c-language/)